# Delete lines except if they contain certain text

Tags: regex, sed

I have a text file in which each line has the following structure but with different values for the single fields so they don't have the same length. For example the author field contains different names.

```
{"cid": "z13k.16", "text": "Lor..ips", "time": "9 months ago", "author": "Jim Boe"}
```

I want now to delete every line except for lines which contain the specific author "John Doe".

Also "John Doe" can appear in other parts of the text. I want to keep the line only if the name is in the "author" category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all data are in single rows use this command in linux:

```
sed -i '/"author": "John Doe"/!d' your_file
```

Or just

```
grep '"author": "John Doe"' your_file > your_file_cleaned
```